# Edit multiple tables in database in django

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have a page with the user can edit the information in database, and this page have more than one table (InformacaoFamilia, Imagens). The images i can delete and insert. But when click in confirm the fields with a legend dont save in database.

In this page have a form with all fields in InformacaoFamilia models, have a image and a textarea with respectivily legend, have all images and the user can select what goes to delete, and for a add news images.

but the legend dont saving in database.

update_facthseets.html

```
    <article>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
                <p class="form-group">
                    {% if field.errors %}
                        <div class="">{{ field.errors.as_text }}</div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <label class="" for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">
                        {{ field.label }}:
                    </label>
                    {{ field }}
                </p>
            {% endfor %}

            <hr>

            Editar Legenda

            {% for image in images %}
                <div class="imagem">
                    <p>
                        <label for="edit-legend-{{ image.id }}">
                        <img src="{{ image.imagens.url }}" alt="{{ image.legenda }}">
                            Legenda: <textarea type="text" name="imagens-{{ image.id }}-legenda" id="edit-legend-{{ image.id }}" value="{{ image.legenda }}">{{ image.legenda }}</textarea>
                        </label>
                    </p>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

            Excluir Imagens
            {% for image in images %}
                <div class="imagem">
                    <!-- <p class="paragrafo-{{ image.id }}"> -->
                        <input type="checkbox" name="delete_image" value="{{ image.id }}" id="delete-image-{{ image.id }}" onchange="marcada('{{ image.id }}')" style="display: none;">
                        <label for="delete-image-{{ image.id }}">
                            <img src="{{ image.imagens.url }}" alt="{{ image.legenda }}">
                            legenda: {{ image.legenda }}
                        </label>
                    <!-- </p> -->
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

            <br>
            <br>
            Adicionar Imagens

            <div id="image-fields">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="image-count" id="image-count-field">
            <button type="button" id="add-image-field" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick=addImageField()>+ Adicionar Imagem</button>
            <p>
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Confirmar</button>
            {% endif %}
            <a href="{% url 'factsheets' %}">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Cancelar</button>
            </a>
            </p>
        </form>
    </article>
```

views.py

```
class FactsheetsUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'update_factsheets.html'
    form_class = FactsheetsUpdateForm
    model = InformacaoFamilias
    success_url = reverse_lazy('factsheets')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Deletando as imagens escolhidas
        delete_images = self.request.POST.getlist('delete_image')
        if delete_images:
            for delete_image_id in delete_images:
                try:
                    image = Imagens.objects.get(pk=delete_image_id)
                    path_delete_image = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'static',str(image.imagens))
                    if os.path.exists(path_delete_image):
                        os.remove(path_delete_image)
                    image.delete()
                except Imagens.DoesNotExist:
                    pass
            messages.success(self.request, 'Images deleted successfully.')
            form = self.get_form()

        if form.is_valid():
            family = form.save(commit=False)
            lista_dados_geneticos=[]
            for i in self.request.POST.getlist('dados_geneticos'):
                lista_dados_geneticos.append(i)
            family.dados_geneticos=lista_dados_geneticos
            family = form.save()

            # Salvando as imagens
            for image_id in range(0, self.request.POST.get('image-count-field') if type(self.request.POST.get('image-count-field')) == int else 1):
                image = self.request.FILES.get(f'imagens-{image_id}-image')
                legend = self.request.POST.get(f'imagens-{image_id}-legenda')
                if image:
                    path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'static','factsheets',self.request.POST.get('familia'))
                    if not os.path.exists(path):
                        os.makedirs(path)
                    img = Image.open(image)
                    image_name = str(date.today())+'id'+str(i)+image.name
                    path_img = os.path.join('factsheets',self.request.POST.get('familia'),image_name)
                    all_path_img = os.path.join('static',path_img)
                    img.save(all_path_img)
                    new_image = Imagens(post=family, familia=family.familia, imagens=path_img, legenda=legend)
                    new_image.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        family_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        family_name = InformacaoFamilias.objects.filter(id=family_id).values_list('familia')
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['images'] = Imagens.objects.filter(familia__in=family_name)
        return context
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

import os

def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('factsheets', instance.post.familia)

# Define InformacaoFamilias
class InformacaoFamilias(models.Model):
    ano = models.IntegerField(help_text="Selecione o ano")
    autor = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    caracteristicas_gerais = models.TextField(verbose_name="Características Gerais",default="")
    diagnoses = models.TextField(verbose_name="Diagnoses")
    dados_geneticos = models.TextField(verbose_name="Dados genéticos",blank=True,null=True)
    familia = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Família',unique=True)
    referencias = models.TextField(verbose_name="Referências",default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.familia}"

# Define Imagens class usando InformacaoFamilias foreign key
class Imagens(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(InformacaoFamilias, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='imagens')
    # Este campo é para acessar a família
    familia = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name='Família',null=True)
    imagens = models.ImageField('Imagem',blank=True,upload_to=get_upload_path)
    legenda = models.TextField(verbose_name="Legenda",default="",blank=True)
```